# Please reopen "How to tell Employer I'm interviewing but don't plan to leave"

Tags: discussion

[How to Tell Employer I'm Interviewing But Don't Plan to Leave](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/116470/how-to-tell-employer-im-interviewing-but-dont-plan-to-leave)

**THIS^^^^^^**

Has been closed as a duplicate of:

[Should I go to an interview I don't intend to accept the job (if offered)?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/should-i-go-to-an-interview-i-dont-intend-to-accept-the-job-if-offered)

**THIS^^^^^^**

These are absolutely not duplicates.

The former is a question as to whether the user should notify his employer that he's going to go on an interview, when he is not going to take the job.  The latter is about whether or not the user should go on an interview if he doesn't intend to take the job.

There is no way the issues are the same.  The latter is about whether or not he'd burn bridges with the company he's interviewing with, the former is about damaging relations with his present employer if he goes on an interview.

The issues are in no way related.  I.E. the latter will in no way shape or form jeopardize his employment, where the former will.

The **ONLY** thing these two posts have in common is going on an interview and not taking the job if offered.

The answers to either are entirely unrelated.

Comment: To the down voters:  Why do you think these are duplicates?

Comment: I suspect it is because `!duplicate != ShouldBeReopened`

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings would be nice to know why though....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed; those are definitely two different questions.

It's reopened now.